# AIogramm. Машина состояний не выполняет первый State без ответа от пользователя

Tags: python, aiogram

При инициализации машины состояний aiogram не начинает работу, не получив какие-либо данные от пользователя.

Машина состояний

```
class FSMComplete(StatesGroup):
    id_task = State()
    obj = State()
```

Cообщение, инициализирующее запуск машины состояний

```
async def watch_task(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:  
        read = await sqlite_db.sql_read2()
        for ret in read:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=f'<b>{ret[0]}</b>\n Описание: {ret[2]}\n Срок выполнения:'
                                                              f' {ret[3]}')
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='^^^', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().
                                   add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'Просмотреть выполнение "{ret[0]}"',
                                                            callback_data=f'watch {ret[1]}')))
```

## Установка id_task машины состояний

```
async def complete_task_start(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    r = callback_query.data.split(' ')
    global id_task_complete
    id_task_complete = r[1]

# В этом месте FSM не переходит к следующему пункту. Проблема решается получением любого сообщения от пользователя, но почему?
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text='Really?', reply_markup=kb_client_or)

    await FSMComplete.id_task.set()
    await callback_query.answer()
```

Следующий шаг

```
async def load_id_task(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await FSMComplete.id_task.set()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['IDtask'] = id_task_complete
    await FSMComplete.next()
    await message.answer('Выберите, какой объект хотите просмотреть', reply_markup=kb_set_obj_all)
    await FSMComplete.obj.set()
```

Регистрация хендлеров

```
def register_handlers_admin(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(complete_task_start, Text(startswith='watch'), state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_id_task, state=FSMComplete.id_task)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_name_task, state=FSMComplete.obj)
```

Comment: А вы декораторы не забыли добавит? Ну или хотя бы эти новомодные регистрации хендлеров в конце.

Comment: декораторы на месте

Comment: Честно говоря я не очень понял проблему. Есть некие данные из бд которые вы перебираете и делаете кучу сообщений с кнопками. После ловите эти кнопки и кидаете что-то в глобальную переменную ну и заодно какое-то сообщение с клавиатурой. Какая суть у последнего хендлера? Зачем он? Как это должно по вашему мнению работать?